Necessary condition for an isomorphism of modules to be a homeomorphism
Let $M$ and $N$ be two filtered $A$-modules with filtrations $(M_n)$ and $(N_n)$ and $u\colon M\to N$ be a morphism of modules. We can show that if $u(M_n)=N_n$ and $u$ is an isomorphism then $u$ is continuous. Indeed, let $O$ be an open subset of $N$. We will show that $u^{-1}(O)$ is open. Let $x\in u^{-1}(O)$. Then $u(x)\in O$ and since $O$ is open there exists $k\in\mathbb{Z}$ such that $u(x)+M_k\subset O$. Applying the inverse to both sides we attain $x+N_k\subset u^{-1}(O)$ which shows that the inverse image is open.
I'm curious about the converse of this statement. Given a morphism $u$ of modules from $M$ to $N$ which is a homeomorphism, do we necessarily have that $u(M_n)=N_n$? (Here I am not assuming that $u$ is a strict morphism of filtered modules. If we assume the morphism to be a morphism of filtered modules then the statement follows since we have that $u(M_n)=N_n\cap u(M)$.)
We can show that the image is contained in some $N_p$ and the inverse image is contained in some $M_k$ directly since these filtrations form a neighborhood basis of 0 but I couldn't figure out how to continue. Is this statement true and if so, how to show it?

Thanks to @Thorgott for this answer:
The statement is false. Let $M$ be any module with a filtration $(M_n)$ such that $M_{k+1}\subsetneq M_k$ for some $k\in \mathbb{Z}$ and let N be a module such that $N=M$ and filtration $(N_n)$ is given by $N_n=M_n$ except for $N_k=M_{k+1}$. Consider the identity map $i\colon M\to N$. This map is clearly a homeomorphism and an isomorphism of modules yet $i(M_{k+1})=N_k$.
